# HTML/CSS - Center Class Trouble

Tags: html, css

I can't get the `.center` class to apply to the following HTML. It gets applied to the `ul` element for some reason, but nothing else. Am I applying it wrong? Does it have something to do with IDs? I thought adding a class to a `div` would apply it to all elements within.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none; /* getting rid of bullet pts */
  padding: 0; /* practice to remove padding so we can set it later */
}

img {
  display: inline;
  width: 200px; /* we set in % or vh(view height) for responsive */
  height: 100px; /* design - changes with page size (phones tablets etc) */
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid 2px black;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Guessing Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap and CSS here-->
</head>

<body>

  <div id='app' class='center'>

    <div id='headers'>
      <!-- Title and subtitles! -->
      <h1 id='title' class='center'> Rav's Cheesy Guessing Game! </h1>
      <h2 id='subtitle'> Guess A Number Between 1-100, You Won't </h2>
    </div>

    <div id='main'>
      <div id='input-parent'>
        <!-- Player's guess input, and submit button -->
        <input id='player-input' class='center' placeholder="#" autofocus maxlength=2>
        <button id='submit-button' type=submit>Go!</button>
      </div>

      <div id='guesses'>
        <ul id='guess-list'>
          <li class='guess'>_</li>
          <li class='guess'>_</li>
          <li class='guess'>_</li>
          <li class='guess'>_</li>
          <li class='guess'>_</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- unordered list of guesses -->
      </div>

      <div id="menu-btns">
        <!-- reset and hint buttons -->
        <button id='reset'>Reset</button>
        <button id='hint'>Hint</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id='footer' class='center'>
    <div>
      <div class=''>
        <img src='fa-logo@2x.png' alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class=''>
        <h4>Project by Ravish Rawal</h4>
      </div>

      <div class=''>
        <img src='grace_hopper_academy.png' alt="image">
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made a edit to the snippet, and now everything looks centered to me. Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: `<img>` is a **void** self-closing element (you guessed it right: therefore it does not needs a closing `</img>` tag)

Comment: You cannot use `<style></style>` inside a `.css` file (sorry for removing it in my edit) - and also check you're closing properly your `<div>` elements.

Comment: Also, think twice before bloating your HTML with classes. I.E: `class='guess'` on every LI element is off, rather set a `class="guess-list"` to your UL element and than do `.guess-list li {` in CSS.

Comment: You were also using the wrong comments syntax for `CSS`. CSS uses `/* Comment */` rather than `//`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Roko - It was the style tags, stupid mistake haha. Really appreciate it.